# I can't define whether graphic cards are working or not.

Tags: linux, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I use the command lspci -vnnn | grep VGA and the output is

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 18) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation GT218 [GeForce 310M] [10de:0a70] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
```

from this I can't understand whether nvidia graphic card is working or not. I was following a tutorial to switch it off but can't estimate it right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine which card is powered on by issuing the following command :

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

At least this works on Archlinux and [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) exists for [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics)